# Use NSNotificationCenter selector for one observer in multiple view controllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, notifications, nsnotificationcenter

Can I use the selector `getUpdate:` in multiple view controllers?  I'm registering my `LevelViewController` as an observer for both `GameViewController` and `WinViewController`.  The latter 2 view controllers both have a back button (which, when pressed, pops you back to `LevelVC`), and the idea with the notification is to tell `LevelVC` whether or not to update the collection view cells (via the `viewWillAppear:` method) when the back button is pressed.

In `viewWillAppear:`, I wouldn't want to call two separate methods (one from `GameVC` and one from `WinVC`) in order to get my update, I just one fluid method that can be used in either.

Here's what I intend (in `LevelVC`):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(getUpdate:)        
                                                 name:@"getUpdateForCell" 
                                               object:nil];
}
```

And incorporate

```
- (void)getUpdate:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSDictionary *data = [notification userInfo];
    // pop
}
```

twice...once in `GameVC`, and the other in `WinVC`.

Is this possible?  Or should I just make two separate notifications?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `NSDictionary` and pass as a value in `userInfo` to determine which `UIViewController` you came from and appropriately handle the situation using an `if` statement.

**Alternatively**

You can use delegates to execute an event when the back button is present and perform appropriate actions on the previous `UIViewController`. Personally i prefer the this approach.

Comment: Maybe I worded it funny, but it's not so much a matter of which `UIViewController` I'm coming from.  Both `GameVC` and `WinVC` will pass back an `NSNumber` with either a 1 or a 0, to notify `LevelVC` in `viewWillAppear:` whether or not to update the cells.   Can I declare and call `getUpdate:` in both `GameVC` and `WinVC`?

Comment: Does that make any sense?

Comment: Well you can just create a `NSDictionary` holding that particular number and pass in `NSNotification` **or** create a delegate and pass this number as an argument and call the `getUpdate:` method!

Comment: I should have been a bit more clearer, you can use the `getUpdate` function **as** the delegate.

Comment: That makes sense and I might incorporate it.  But again, can I use that method in two separate view controllers?  I'm new to notifications so this is why I ask

Comment: If you mean just use one function definition? Then no. You will have to type the body of the function in both `UIViewController`. If you mean have the same function declaration, then yes. To have the same function definition i.e. Not have to write the same body twice you will have write a separate class that will hold the function body and call this class from inside both your `UIViewController`. Does that make sense?